# Intuition of Artin's Linear Independence Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, characters

Let $G$ be a group and $k$ be a field. A character of $G$ is a group homomorphism $G \to k^{\times}$.

**Theorem** (Artin)**.** Distinct characters $\chi_1, \dots, \chi_n : G \to k^\times$ are linearly independent in $\operatorname{Map}(G,k)$.

(Special case in a different setting: Let $L/K$ be a finite separable field extension, $\tau : K \to \overline{L}$ an embedding, then there are exactly $n = [L:K]$ embeddings $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n : L \to \overline{L}$ preserving $\tau$. These are linearly independent over $\Omega$.)

But why? I know the standard proof but I fail to really grasp why this statement should be true. The best I can come up with is the following: Take a linear combination $$ a_1 \chi_1 + \dots + a_n \chi_n = 0, $$ then by plugging in elements from $G$, we get a bunch of linear relations, e.g. by plugging in the identity element $e \in G$, we get $a_1 + \dots + a_n = 0$. Since those are a lot of relations, they should eventually give us $a_1 = \dots = a_n = 0$.

However, this is extremely vague. Does anyone have a better intuitive explanation of this result?

Comment: I dont have a solution, but maybe this could be a possible direction: since $\chi_{i}$ are distinct, (maybe?) there is some x in G so that $\chi_{1} (x) \neq ... \neq \chi_{n} (x)$. Since $\chi_{i} (x^k)= \chi_{i}(x)^k $ we can look at the corresponding, appropriately sized van-der-monde matrix $ A_{ij} = \chi_{i} (x)^j $, so showing the characters are linearly independent is equivalent to showing A is invertible.

Comment: What do you mean with I know the standard proof ?

Comment: @reuns Well, there is a standard proof that appears in textbooks/papers over and over again (choose non-trivial linear combination with minimal number of generators and show that it wasn‘t minimal). And yes, they are not but by restricting them to the unit groups of the fields we recover the general case. (I will read your answer later, thank you for it already!)

Comment: @reuns They don‘t commute with what? Evidently, $\sigma_j |_{L^\times} : L^\times \to \overline{L}^\times$ are distinct group homomorphisms.

Comment: @reuns Please don't remove comments like this, that makes it hard for other readers to understand what we were discussing. So to make it clear, my last comment was a reply to something like "The $\sigma_j$ don't commute, this is a completely different setting".

Comment: ...Another comment removed - I always wonder why this is allowed hours/days after posting a comment. The comment before that was "The $\sigma_j$ are not homomorphisms into some $k^{\times}$.".  (That is what I answered in my first comment.)

Answer (score 1):

You meant $G$ is an arbitrary infinite group. Viewing the $\chi_j$ as characters on the abelian group $G/\cap_j \ker(\chi_j)$, they are assumed distinct thus they must disagree on some finitely generated subgroup $\langle s_1,\ldots,s_n\rangle$.

Assuming $a_1\ne 0$, take a polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^K c_k x^k\in k[x]$ such that $f(\chi_1(s_1))=1$ and $f(\chi_j(s_1))=0$ for $\chi_j(s_1)\ne \chi_1(s_1)$. Then for all $g$, $$\sum_{l,\chi_l(s_1)=\chi_1(s_1)}a_l \chi_l(g)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j f(\chi_j(s_1)) \chi_j(g)=\sum_{k=0}^K c_k \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \chi_j(s_1^k g)=0$$
Thus we get a linear dependence between the characters agreeing with $\chi_1$ at $s_1$, repeating with $s_2,s_3,\ldots$ we'll reach a contradiction, ie. that two characters are the same on $\langle s_1,\ldots,s_n\rangle$.

Comment: G is not assumed to be finite. And the questioner is not looking for a proof, rather for an argument why the statement should be intuitively right.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that $G$ is an arbitrary infinite group, it is just an arbitrary group... And as ZPlaya already mentioned, I am not looking for a proof, I know full well how to prove this result.

Comment: Similar to the comments towards to original question, please don't edit your answer entirely that it becomes unclear what the conversation was about. For instance, ZPlaya's first sentence doesn't seem to make sense - but of course it was directed to your original answer where you used finiteness of $G$.

Comment: @QiZhu Please be respectful with those taking the time to work on your problem... Do you have anything to say about my 3 lines answer, does it answer to your question ? Misinterpreting a question-comment happens all the time, the edit and delete buttons are made for that.

Comment: @reuns I don‘t think I was being disrespectful... However sorry, if you felt so. Of course misinterpreting is okay and nobody judges anyone for mistakes but not being able to follow a certain thread is simply not what anyone wishes for. As I‘ve already stated above, your answer does not answer my question. Nonetheless, thank you for your time.

Comment: @QiZhu How does it not answer ? Most people are satisfied when they find a 3 lines proof for something they thought was non-obvious.

Comment: @reuns I am simply not looking for a proof but rather heuristics. The standard proof is short as well.